# Step-sized linearly spaced vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Having a background in Python I am familiar with the numpy library. In numpy there is a function called `arange(start,end,step-size)`. It is a very useful function. Unlike `linspace(start,end,total points)`, you can (without pre-calculating amount of total points) specify how small step you want.

I have tried to look for a similar function in Matlab (R2015a), but can only see two relevant choices : [`linspace`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) and [`colon`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html). Is there such a function in Matlab ?

Comment: What's wrong with colon? `start:step-size:end`

Comment: AFAIK, `colon` would be the closest cousin.

Comment: Although in numpy the interval is half-open, so they might differ in the final value.

Comment: I thought that the step-size could only be an integer for  `colon`. I see now that `colon` is perfect for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `colon` function you mentioned in your question, using three arguments `start:step-size:end` , seems to have the same ouput as `arange(start,end,step-size)`.

```
In[1] numpy.arange(0,0.5,0.1)
Out[1] array([0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
```

And in Matlab

```
E = 0:0.1:0.4
E = 0   0.1000   0.2000   0.3000   0.4000
```

Edit :

As mentionned by Beaker, the `end` is inclusive in Matlab, but exclusive in Python.

Comment: Indeed it does! When I glanced at the documentation, I presumed that it could only handle integer numbers as step-size. I see in the documentation (now that I looked closer) there is even an example with float step-size.

Comment: It is important to note that the end of the range differs between numpy and Matlab.